Not able to setup WSO2 APIM Analytics
Experts! help me on this.
We are doing evaluation of WSO2 APIM  in our on-perm setup .

Installed APIM 4.3.0 successfully.
Now I have to setup analytics dashboard. But I don’t see link to download Analytics 4.3.0.
Is APIM + Analytics will work? Or Do we need WSO2 Stream Integrator setup for analytics to work…

Please share download and documentation link

APIM 4.x versions do not have a downloaded Analytics component provided by WSO2. Instead, you can use the WSO2 Choreo Analytics which is a cloud analytics solution. You can refer [1] for more information. There are other options such as ELK or Datadog as well. You can find more about those options as well through the documentation.
[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/choreo-analytics/getting-started-guide/
